# Storage fake with factory laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to use storage fake in the delete, but I dont know how to simulate upload file with factory. My test:

```
 $actualCategory = factory(Category::class)->create();

    $this->json(
        'DELETE',
        '/api/category/' . $actualCategory->id
    )->assertStatus(200)
        ->assertJsonStructure([
            'success',
            'data' => [
                'id',
                'name',
                'image_code',
                'updated_at',
                'deleted_at',
                'created_at'
            ]
        ]);

    $this->assertSoftDeleted('categories', [
        'id' => $actualCategory->id,
        'name' => $actualCategory->name
    ]);

    Storage::disk('categories')->assertMissing($actualCategory->image_code);
```

If I comment this-> json is still working for more than not delete the photo

and my factory is:

```
$factory->define(Category::class, function (Faker $faker) {

return [
    'name' => "Category {$faker->firstName}",
    'image_code' => $faker->image('/tmp', 300, 300)
];
```

});

Answer (score -2):

```
class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testAlbumUpload()
    {
        Storage::fake('photos');

        $response = $this->json('POST', '/photos', [
            UploadedFile::fake()->image('photo1.jpg'),
            UploadedFile::fake()->image('photo2.jpg')
        ]);

        // Assert one or more files were stored...
        Storage::disk('photos')->assertExists('photo1.jpg');
        Storage::disk('photos')->assertExists(['photo1.jpg', 'photo2.jpg']);

        // Assert one or more files were not stored...
        Storage::disk('photos')->assertMissing('missing.jpg');
        Storage::disk('photos')->assertMissing(['missing.jpg', 'non-existing.jpg']);
    }
}
```